# SSIS Web service task cannot connect to remote server

Tags: web-services, azure, ssis, connection

I created an Integration Services Project with an web service task which calls a web service hosted on Azure.

I've configured the Http Connection in Visual studio 2013, only introduced the service URL and the testConnection suceded.

runnuing the package i get an error message saying that it is not possible to connect to the remote server.

> Error: 0xC002F304 at Web Service Task, Web Service Task: An error
>   occurred with the following error message:
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException:
>   The Web Service threw an error during method execution. The error is:
>   Não é possível estabelecer ligação com o servidor remoto.    em
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebMethodInvokerProxy.InvokeMethod(DTSWebMethodInfo
>   methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection)    em
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTaskUtil.Invoke(DTSWebMethodInfo
>   methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection, VariableDispenser
>   taskVariableDispenser)    em
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTask.executeThread()".
>   Task failed: Web Service Task

Any ideas on what is causing the task to fail?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify serviceUrl as http://yourhost/service.asmx?WSDL